# Force command inside CMakeLists.txt on consecutive build runs

Tags: cmake

I have a CMakeLists.txt file that shall behave differently in every run (basically without caching). Example:

```
set(MY_LIB ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib/libmy_lib.so)

if (EXISTS ${MY_LIB})
  message("External project already compiled, skipping")
  # do something special here
else()
  # compile an ExternalProject_Add that creates the ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib/libmy_lib.so file
endif()
```

In the first run, the libmy_lib.so doesn't exist and it runs the ExternalProject_Add.

In the second run (without cleaning the cmake/CMakeCache.txt) it shall not run the ExternalProject anymore but instead go into the first section of the if-statement. However, in the second run cmake cached it's state and never enters the first section.

Is there a way how I can prevent this? On first run, it shall always go into the else branch and in all consecutive runs it shall run the first one.

Edit: I want to enforce it from within the CMakeLists.txt file without clearing the cmake cache files manually and without running cmake with additional arguments.

Thanks!

Edit 2: this issue was caused by our build tool around cmake... cmake wasn't run again. solved!

Comment: "in the second run cmake cached it's state and never enters the first section" - Eh? No, CMake doesn't cache the `MY_LIB` variable, which is not declared with CACHE parameter. Have you ever **re-run** `cmake` after the first build? You don't need to pass additional arguments to cmake upon re-running, but you need to re-run it **manually**, as *automatic* re-run on `make` isn't performed because nothing has been changed in the scripts.

Comment: oh you're right... this issue was caused by the tool we use around cmake... it didn't call cmake. THanks so much and sorry for the stupid question...